# boost::multiprecision:int128_t(-1) not equal to int128_t ("0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF") but their difference is zero

Tags: boost-multiprecision

I'm testing boost::multiprecision:int128_t using VS 2022. The value `int128_t (-1)` is not equal to `int128_t ("0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")`, but their difference is zero as expected. The issue is illustrated by

```
void TestEqualityof_int128_t ()
{
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;

    const int128_t minusOne ("0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");

    // Using difference to detect equality
    if ((minusOne - int128_t (-1)) == 0)
        std::cout << "Using test (minusOne - int128_t (-1)), are equal." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Using test (minusOne - int128_t (-1)), are not equal." << std::endl;

    // Using equality
    if (minusOne == int128_t (-1))
        std::cout << "Using test (minusOne == int128_t (-1)), are equal." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Using test (minusOne == int128_t (-1)), are not equal." << std::endl;
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
Using test (minusOne - int128_t (-1)), are equal.
Using test (minusOne == int128_t (-1)), are not equal.
```

This issue is common to any integer.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question to boostorg, and Maddock replied that this is not a bug. The extended precision integer implementations of boost does not guarantee that `(x-y) == 0 <=> x == y`. In addition, their integers are not two's complement. You may follow this [link](https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/issues/492) to read his reply.

Beware, I can't validate at this moment, but suspect that boost::multiprecision::int128_t defaults to __int128_t in linux which tells me that the same code in Windows will behave differently than the same code in linux.